# ActionBar is not working If selects another language

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

My app is working fine, But if I **select language other then English language**  from phone's Setting, Then it doesn't show Action bar. Even `getSupportActionBar()` returns null.

I am using `ActionBarSherlock` library to show Action bar.

I wonder if anybody else faced/facing similar issue, as I could not find similar thread anywhere.

Edit:- I changed language to Portuguese , I have string.xml for portuguese as well.And it does not show actionbar now.

Comment: I just tried it and it works normally for me. I wonder what's wrong.

Comment: Yeah even I am not sure. I just choose Portuguese as language, and we have support(string.xml) for this language. And it stopped showing action bar.
Are you using SherlockActionBar and have support for the changed language too?

Comment: Do you have a styles.xml file in each language folder ?

Comment: Nope? does it make effect?

Comment: Yeah, I changed the language to French and SherlockActionBar worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having styles.xml in other language folders too. And they were not having sherlock.theme set in them.

This was the issue.